# Can't get the correct integer value of a float

Tags: php, integer

I'm sorry but I'm going nuts with this. It is such a simple problem and I can't solve it.

I have this:

```
var_dump($match['matchId']);
$REFERENCETHISAGAINSON = intval($match['matchId']);
var_dump($REFERENCETHISAGAINSON);
```

And for some hateful reason it prints:

```
float 2245345126
int -2049622170
```

just... why?... I can't even...

Comment: A 32bit int is too small for that value...

Comment: There are two standard libraries in PHP handling the arbitrary length/precision numbers: BC Math and GMP. Use these libraries for using big numbers.

Comment: Thank you! So simple and I couldn't find the reason of it...